# Inscribed circles

Tags: geometry

> Triangle $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles triangle. Point $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$, and $M$
>   is lying on $AD$. Circle $k_1(O_1;r_1)$ is inscribed in $\triangle AMC$ and
>   touches $CM$ in $P$. Circle $k_2(O_2;r_2)$ is inscribed in $\triangle BMC$
>   and touches $CM$ in $Q$. Show that $MD=PQ$.
>
> [image]

We have equal tangent segments: $AE=AG, CG=CP,ME=MP,MH=MQ,BH=BI,CQ=CI$.

$MH=MQ$, thus $MD+DH=MP+PQ$

How can I prove $DH=MP$?

Comment: I noticed that $PQ=BI-AG$. I'm not sure if that is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have not used the fact that $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{PQ} &= \overline{MQ} - \overline{MP}\\
&= \frac12\left(\overline{BM}+\overline{MC}-\overline{BC}\right) - \frac12\left(\overline{AM}+\overline{MC}-\overline{AC}\right)\\
&= \frac12\left(\overline{BM}-\overline{AM}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

And this is $\overline{DM}$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't get what happens after $PQ=MQ-MP$.

Comment: This is a fact for circles inscribed in triangles. In your diagram, $\overline{MQ} = \overline{MH} =$ half perimeter minus the opposite side ($\overline{BC}$). Similarly $\overline{BH} = \overline{BI} =$ half perimeter minus the opposite side ($\overline{CM}$). To prove this, try writing down equations and solve them.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! May I ask why $\dfrac{1}{2}(BM-AM)=DM$?

Comment: Since $D$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{BM} = \overline{BD} + \overline{DM}$ and so on.

Comment: Can you continue it for me? I really messed up.

Comment: $\overline{AM} = \overline{AD} - \overline{DM}$, and $\overline{AD} = \overline{BD}$. What you really need to write down everything given by the problem clearly.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Thank you! I am trying to look deeper into the problem. I am playing with the ratios of the segments. Is it possible to find $AM:BM$ if we know $PQ=\dfrac{3}{7}AB$?

Answer (score 0):

Since the points $EMDH$ occur in that sequence along a line, we know that
$DE + DH = EM + HM.$

If you can show that
$DE - DH = HM - EM$
then from these two equations you can conclude that $DH = EM = MP.$

From $PQ = MQ - MP$ you can easily find that $HM - EM = PQ.$

Showing that $DE - DH = PQ$ takes more steps (at least the way I did it). You can start with $PQ = CP - CQ$ but then you have to chase differences of segment lengths all the way around the outside of the triangle, using the facts that $AC = BC$ and $AD = BD.$