# Ratios of tangent segments

Tags: geometry

I am trying to look deeper into the problem that I posted earlier - [Inscribed circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3373088/inscribed-circles)
. Let me give you it again:

> Triangle $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles triangle. Point $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$, and $M$
>   is lying on $AD$. Circle $k_1(O_1;r_1)$ is inscribed in $\triangle AMC$ and
>   touches $CM$ in $P$. Circle $k_2(O_2;r_2)$ is inscribed in $\triangle BMC$
>   and touches $CM$ in $Q$. Show that $MD=PQ$.
>
> [image]

Is it possible to find $AM: BM$ if we know $PQ=\dfrac{3}{7}AB$? If $PQ=3x$, then $AB=7x$ and $AM+BH+DH=4x$.